# What does it mean for a map to be "coadded"?

Tags: astrophysics, gravitational-waves, data-analysis

So there is this [wiktionary definition of coaddition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coaddition), but it's rather brief. Could anyone expand on this, perhaps giving a short example and explaining why its useful?

The context that I initially came across 'coaddition' in is the [BICEP2 gravitational waves paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3985). The paper seems to assume that the reader is likely to be familiar with the term. Is it something that any 'fully cooked' astrophysicist would know about?

Comment: in chapter G, _"We next proceed to coadded maps accumulating over
phases and pairs."_ ; it seems that it is the join map of a lot of partial observations . Co-added as a _tricky_ superposition of smallest views from different telescopes

Comment: I consider myself a fully cooked astrophysicist (in the sense that I received a doctorate for astrophysics work not to long ago) and have never heard the term.

Comment: It's definitely a common term. It's used in pretty much every survey, whether the target is the CMB, galaxies, or supernovae.

Comment: Well this is interesting, @ChrisWhite might I enquire what area you work in, is it theoretical or experimental? Kyle cannot have graduated that long ago, and you cannot get a PhD without reading *some* papers, so I wonder where this disparity comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coadding is not an especially precise term, I don't think, but in general it just means stacking or combining images --- very literally, just 'adding-together'.  I usually hear this in terms of stacking images of the same field (e.g. of an optical image), but I think it can also be used to mean mosaic images, even in arbitrary parameter spaces.

See for example:
https://sites.google.com/site/applegatearchive/astro-data-reduction#TOC-2.-Coadding-a.k.a.-Stacking-or-Combing-Images
http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/holtz/a535.fall08/ay535notes/node61.html